# NetworkAdapter.GetConnectedProfile Threading Requirements

Tags: c#, wifi, .net-7.0

I am attempting to manage wifi stuff in my app and need to get the profile for the currently connected network. To the best of my knowledge the code is correct, but I am getting an threading error.

I have verified that this is executing on thread 1. This is the only code in the app that accesses these apis. I don't know what thread it's expecting me execute this on.

This is a WPF app using winRT libraries.

The error:

`The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))`

The code:

```
var access = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
if (access != WiFiAccessStatus.Allowed) { Networks = new List<WiFiAvailableNetwork>(); return; }

var adapters = await WiFiAdapter.FindAllAdaptersAsync();
if (!adapters.Any()) return;

Adapter = adapters.First();
await Adapter.ScanAsync();
Networks = Adapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks;

IReadOnlyList<ConnectionProfile> profiles = Array.Empty<ConnectionProfile>();
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => profiles = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles());
ConnectionProfiles = profiles;

ConnectionProfile profile = default;
try { profile = await Adapter.NetworkAdapter.GetConnectedProfileAsync(); } // <= fails here
catch (Exception ex) { Log.Exception(ex); }
```

I have also tried the two alternatives below and they fail with the same error.

```
await Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () => profile = await Adapter.NetworkAdapter.GetConnectedProfileAsync());
await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () => profile = await Adapter.NetworkAdapter.GetConnectedProfileAsync());
```

Comment: Put the whole function in `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` alternatively remove that from `NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles()`. It's a COM call, which is not thread-safe.

Comment: @Charlieface This did it, thank you. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These objects and methods use COM calls, which are normally not thread-safe. Just putting `NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles()` into an `Invoke` is not enough, the whole access to the objects returned must be on the same thread.

So either put the whole function into `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` or alternatively remove that from `NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles()`.